# Loading jQuery functions in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-routing

What's the proper way for loading jQuery functions in Angular 2?

I've added my jQuery to `ngAfterViewInit`. It works fine for one route, but if I navigate to another one (e.g. from `id: 1` to `id: 2`), it doesn't work for the second one (I'm using the same component for both).

It works using `ngAfterViewChecked` but, then, the function is executed multiple times (after every change in the view).

This is my jQuery function:

```
$('.chips').on('chip.add', (e, chip) => {
  console.log(e, chip);
});
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y55c3l8YDqY3fnHOlFhO?p=preview)**

Comment: Could you demonstrate it on a plunker?

Comment: Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y55c3l8YDqY3fnHOlFhO?p=preview).

Comment: Router reuses your component so `constructor` and `ngAfterViewInit` aren't firing

Comment: any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: `It works using ngAfterViewChecked but, then, the function is executed multiple times (after every change in the view)` When you say `$(.chips)` you only refer to the already rendered elements. Any new element will require you to add it again and that is how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution for your problem might look like this:

1) You need to import `NgZone`

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

2) Inject it in your constructor

```
constructor(
    ...
    private ngZone: NgZone 
) {}
```

3) Add some code that does some magic in your `goTo` method

```
goTo(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/detail', id]);
  if(id === 3) { 
    this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(this.ngAfterViewInit);
  }
}
```

This way when you go to 3 page `ngAfterViewInit` method will be executed after change detection

4) Don't forget to import the `first` operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
```

Here's **[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/9mziDk82tkPwWbdd0Lxr?p=preview)**